# Form Label doesn't route to controller

Tags: laravel, routes, laravelcollective

how do I make Form::label route to my Controller function. When I change Form::label to Form::submit it works. In the route file a create a post statement. What's wrong with my Form?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">   
        @foreach($groupsrequest as $grouprequest)
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block">   
        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'mgmtgroups_approvel', $grouprequest->group_name]) !!} 
            {{Form::label($grouprequest->group_name) }}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </a>
        @endforeach   
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

form label take for and name as the following

```
 {!! Form::label('group', $grouprequest->group_name) !!}
```

Comment: What is 'group'?

Comment: its  the for value

Comment: <label for="group">$grouprequest->group_name</label>

Answer (score 0):

The Form::label() it is only to show the label html tag:

```
<label></label>
```

So, the only thing you are doing there is:

```
<label for="{{ $grouprequest->group_name }} "> </label>
```

You need to set an action to submit your form, you can do it with the Form::submit(), Form::label is not an action trigger

Comment: Is it possible to use a action trigger in an label? Or what have I to do to take this function like submit in an label?

Comment: Why do you want to use a label for that?. You can use javascript or Jquery. $("#label_id).click(function(){ $("form").submit(); });